# Nested If, Else If, Else

Tags: scala

I've just got onto nested if statements in Scala and I've seen examples on here which suggest this syntax is correctly however the { under else if and second to last } are giving me "( expected" and invalid start of expression.

```
object NestedIf2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = 30
    var y = 10

    if ( x == 30 ) {
      if ( y == 10 ) {
        println("X = 30 and Y = 10")
      }
    } else if {
      if ( y == 20 ) {
        println("X = 30 and Y = 20")
      }
    } else {
      if ( y == 30 ) {
        println("X = 30 and Y = 30")
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that `if` statement has no condition (the expression that evaluates to a boolean).

Comment: I just want to mention, this would be a perfect fit for [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html]). It makes your code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you follow these rules:

- Every `if` keyword should be followed by a *condition*
- An `else` clause can only follow an `if` clause

Applied to your code:

```
if (x == 30) {
  if (y == 10) {
    println("X = 30 and Y = 10")
  } else if (y == 20) {
    println("X = 30 and Y = 20")
  } else if (y == 30) {
    println("X = 30 and Y = 30")
  }
}
```